# mciSendString() setaudio volume error 261

Tags: c++, winapi, audio, mci

I'm using MCI to do some sound-related stuff, and everything works, except I cannot alter the volume. I have the following code:

```
mciSendStringA("open res/theme.wav type waveaudio alias maintheme", nullptr, 0, nullptr);
MCIERROR error = mciSendStringA("setaudio maintheme volume to 50", nullptr, 0, nullptr);
```

`error` is 261. The program works fine but the volume does not change. Any suggestions on what's wrong? (Two pages of google searching and there's nothing)

Comment: There are alternative ways to set the wave audio volume.  http://support.microsoft.com/KB/139098

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation:

[setaudio command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd798662.aspx)

> The setaudio command sets values associated with audio playback and capture. **Digital-video and VCR devices recognize this command.**
>
> ...
>
> lpszAudio
>   Flag for audio playback and capture. **The following table lists device types that recognize the setaudio command** and the flags used by each type.
>
> **digitalvideo**
>   **vcr**

Your audio playback is using a **waveaudio** device, which does not support the `setaudio` command.

In order to set the volume of audio playback, you will have to switch to the **WaveOut** API for playback, then you can use [`waveOutSetVolume()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd743874.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

`Error 261` according to [these](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa228215%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) error codes is an `MCIERR_UNRECOGNIZED_COMMAND` error. The error in itself is pretty self explanatory: You are sending an unrecognized command.

Comment: @bojoradarial You would need to change the string you are passing to the function, as it is an unrecognized command.

Comment: @bojoradarial Can you show me the 'results' you are looking at?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a solution but just a workaround. It works perfectly fine if you use mp3 files. To load an mp3 file:

```
mciSendStringA("open [file].mp3 type mpegvideo alias [soundalias]", nullptr, 0, nullptr);
```

The setaudio instruction will then work. However, I don't know if there's a way of getting this to work with wav files...

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into a similar issue earlier, I was able to Play/Pause/Loop mp3's with MCI. But failed to Adjust the volume. But Adding a WaveOut API solved problem.

```
HWAVEOUT hwo;
waveOutSetVolume(hwo, dwVolume);
```

where `dwVolume` according to [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mmeapi/nf-mmeapi-waveoutsetvolume) can be from 0x0000 to 0xFFFF
and if the device supports left and right audio playback 0xFFFF becomes 0xFFFFFFFF and vice versa

for eg:

SILENT = 0,

LOW = 858993459,

NORMAL = 1717986918,

MEDIUM = -1717986919,

HIGH = -858993460,

VERY HIGH = -1

(these sample values are decimals converted from its original hex value such as 0x11111111. use `long long int` when declaring variables)